# Post Request Works in Postman But Not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, request, postman

I have a post request which works fine in postman in curl.
[image]

```bash
(base) a@DESKTOP-DGPCO9D:~/ef-firebase-functions$ curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/ef/us-central1/getNonceToSign' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
    "address" : "0x874814"
}'
{"nonce":"8855"}(base) a@DESKTOP-DGPCO9D:~/ef-firebase-functions$
```

When I try to use the method in javascript I get several errors, about cors and failing to fetch. I am unsure why as this is the generated javascript code from postman. I initially saw recommendations to put `await` in front of the fetch since the call is async but this did not  fix the errors.

Anyone else run into this issue using postman's generated requests?

```js
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
      address: "0x874814",
    });

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
    };

    await fetch(
      "http://127.0.0.1:5001/ef/us-central1/getNonceToSign",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

[image]

Comment: Your server has a CORS issue.

Comment: You were correct. I had to wrap my function with Cors middleware and it works perfect now! Cors provides such odd behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Remove JSON.stringify from your raw variable and try again.

```
  var raw = {
      address: "0x874814",
    };
```